# Integrating partial fractions

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I have

## $\int{\frac{2x+1}{x^2+4x+4}}dx$

Factorising the denominator I have

## $\int{\frac{2x+1}{(x+2)(x+2)}}dx$

From there I split the top term into two parts to make it easier to integrate

## $\int{\frac{2x+1}{(x+2)(x+2)}}dx$ = $\int{\frac{A}{(x+2)}+\frac{B}{(x+2)}}dx$

## =$\int{\frac{A(x+2)}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{B(x+2)}{(x+2)^2}}dx$

Therefore

## $2x+1 = A(x+2) +B(x+2)$

This is where I would normally use a substitution method to eliminate either the A term or B term by letting x = something like -2, which would get rid of the A and usually leave me with the B term to solve. However since they are the same I'm not sure what to do.

I've been told to try evaluate the co-efficients, but am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to try a split like

$$\frac{2 x+1}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B x}{(x+2)^2}$$

Then $A+B=2$ and $2 A=1$.  The decomposition is then

$$\frac{2 x+1}{(x+2)^2} = \frac12 \frac1{x+2} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{x}{(x+2)^2}$$

Comment: Is it $Bx$? I doubt

Comment: @semsem: you doubt what?  Check the work, it is correct.  I could have done just $B$ as well.  The reason either way works is that one may add and subtract $2$ in the numerator of the second fraction to change the representation.

Comment: Ok, you are right

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\int{\frac{2x+1\color{red}{+3-3}}{x^2+4x+4}}dx=2\ln|x+2|+\frac{3}{x+2}+C$$

Comment: This is the best what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to solve this with respect to polynomials:

$2x+1=Ax+2A+Bx+2B$

$2x+1=x(A+B)+(2A+2B)$

$A+B=2 \rightarrow  B=2-A$

$2A+2B=1$

$2A+4-2A=1\rightarrow 4=1$

This is contradiction! You have made an mistake in step where you split the term into two fractions, you should have done it like this:

$\frac{2x+1}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}$

and then proceed like usual.

$A(x+2)+B=2x+1$

$A=2$

$2A+B=1$

$B=-3$

$\int \frac{2}{x+2}+\frac{-3}{(x+2)^2}dx=2ln(x+2)+\frac{3}{x+2}+C$

Answer (score 1):

In this case we a **linear repeated factor** so we split it like
$$\frac{A}{(x+2)}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{A(x+2)+B}{(x+2)^2}$$
and hence 
$$2x+1=A(x+2)+B=Ax+2A+B$$
then by equating coefficients 
$$A=2,\\2A+B=1\implies B=-3$$

Comment: How did you get A=2 from that?

Comment: @user88720 i edited it